# XPath Header 1 with Class

Tags: python, xpath

I'm finding an Xpath to extract the **article's title** from this link (and similar links like it): http://www.workforce.com/2017/09/27/employers-embrace-telemedicine-employees-exhibit-uncertainty/

My code for the Xpath is this

```
#Text path to extract from each url found within the initial crawling stage.
texts = data.xpath("//h1[contains(@class, 'entry-title')]/text()")
```

Link to image with more of the inspected element code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiFyp.jpg

```
#General pseudocode
<article id="post-26922">
     <div class="basic-content-wrap cf">
          <div class="basic-content-wrap cf">
               <div class="before-article-title">
               #Desired Line to get text from
               <h1 class="entry-title">
                    Text
               </h1>
```

Is there an Xpath statement to extract this information **without** having a reference to the article ID, but more directly at the div class or even the h1 class itself?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, guys. I posted this being silly.

I found my own solution to this problem.

```
#HR Edit
# import python packages

import requests
from lxml import html
import csv
import pandas as pd

# the entire crawling process

openfile = open("data/HR.csv", "rb")
r = csv.reader(openfile)
HR_raw = []

for i in r:
    url = i[0]
    print url  # to know the status of web crawling
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = html.fromstring(r.text)
    #Extracts the headers from each article.
    texts = data.xpath("//h1[contains(@class, 'entry-title')]/text()") 
    raw = ''.join(str(i.encode("utf-8")) for i in texts)
    hfinaldata = raw.replace('\r','').replace('\n','').replace('\r','').replace('\t','')    
    HR_raw.append([hfinaldata])

openfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with and didn't works

```
response.xpath('//h1[@class="product-name"]/a/text()').get()
```

and then below line of code works for me

```
response.xpath('//h1[contains(@class,"product-name")]/a/text()').get()
```